# Загрузка одного и того же fxml с разными обработчиками

Tags: javafx, java

Всем доброго времени суток!

При работе с javaFX, в частности с использованием Scene Builder столкнулся со следующей проблемой...

Дано:

1. Имеется файл fxml, содержащий Anchor Pane (fxml получен из Scene Builder);
2. Для Anchor Pane не задан Controller Class.
3. Этот fxml загружается в Java Application средствами FXMLLoader.

Необходимо:

1. После загрузки этого самого Anchor Pane установить ему значение Controller Class. (что-то вроде setControllerClass)
2. Это нужно для того, чтобы загружать один и тот же fxml, но вешать на них разные обработчики.

Вопрос: возможно ли это, и если да - то как реализуется?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось достаточно простым - класс controller устанавливается до загрузки fxml в сам загрузчик FXMLLoader:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlURL);
MyClassController controller = new MyClassController();
fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
fxmlLoader.load();

AnchorPane pane = fxmlLoader.getRoot();
```